# how to use "where...in" in subsonicproject

Tags: subsonic3

I am using subsonicproject and the activerecord pattern.

I have a database with three tables: Cities, Concerthalls, Concerts. Each Concerthall has a foreign-key relationship to a City. Each Concert has a foreign-key relationship to a Concerthall.

I would like to retrieve all concerts within a given city. So I need to get all the Concerthall-ids for a city and pass them to subsonicproject. In "normal" sql I would use the "where ... in"-statement, but how do I do it with subsonicproject?

I am thinking about something like (pseudocode):
List concertHallsId=xxxxxxx;
Concerts.Find(concert.ConcertHallId in concertHallIds);

thanks
Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like:

```
var concertHallIds = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
var concerts = from c in db.concerts
               where concertHallIds.Contains(c.ConcertHallId)
               select c;
```

At least, that is the Linq version. Basically though, you should be ale to use `.Contains()` on your collection of concert hall ids, and SS puts those values into an `in` clause in the SQL.